# How to make server side form validation compatible with screen reader

Tags: php, asp.net, xhtml, accessibility, screen-readers

if screen reader fill any content wrong then how to give info (if javascript is disabled) to user to go that field any fill the correct value.

with JavasSript we can show javascript alert but if JavaScript is disabled then?

I need a solution for both ASP.NET 2.0 and PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main things you should do:

**Make it clear there was a problem** by displaying an information message at the top of the page.

**Place error messages inside label elements** so they will be read in Forms mode. Make sure you have only one label element per input (some screen readers can't cope with multiple labels).

Comment: do you know any example form . ok i found you are saying like this http://green-beast.com/gbcf-v3/test-form.php#results

Comment: Examples? Really?! This is basic form stuff. `<p>There was a problem</p><div><label for='foo'>Foo (this field is required but was left blank</label><input id='foo'></div>`

Comment: this is also good example http://www.tbs-sct.gc.ca/clf2-nsi2/tb-bo/td-dt/ead-eca-eng.asp#cn_5.0_afwcie

Comment: This article explains a bit on how to accessibly display errors messages dynamically upon submission of a form:
http://juicystudio.com/article/dom-screen-readers.php

The example gives you a quick feel for the effect the author intends:
http://juicystudio.com/experiments/form.php